# Removing element from array if difference between consecutive element in 1 in R

Tags: arrays, r, sorting

I have a  problem when I am trying to remove an element from a vector if its difference from the next element is less than one. The basic algorithm is:

```
for i in 1:length(a){
  if a[i+1]-a[i] ==1
  remove a[i]
}
```

I tried implementing in R by following loop

```
y <- sample(1:8,8,replace = F)
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  if (y[i+1]-y[i] ==1)
    {y<-y[-i]}
}
```

it gave me error Error: unexpected '==' in: the loopI tried another way of:

```
y <- sample(1:8,8,replace = F)
y <- y[diff!=1]
```

it gave me error saying comparison not possible for some cases.
Can somebody let me know easy way of implementing it in R?

Comment: I want to remove first element of consecutive pair

Comment: so there is no much data.Y <- sample(1:8,8,replace = f) will give 8 random numbers for an array.and thats good enough for test I believe.

Comment: If you have a triplet, eg 6 7 8, you want to keep only 8, correct?

Comment: yes thats correct Beauvel

Comment: This works? `y[sapply(1:(length(y)-1), function(i) y[i+1] - y[i]) != 1]`

Comment: yes ! that works .thanks

Comment: It has an issue with the last element, I'll fix that and post as an answer.

Comment: it's better to use diff and a vectorized solution if your vector is quite long (but this is rarely the case).